# How to break dependence between tables dynamically rendered in R Shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In the below code, I took one of the examples from https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-app-with-dynamic-number-of-datatables/2405/4 for dynamically adding tables. The example used tables rendered with DT and I made minor modifications to use it for rhandsontable.

However, I'm having trouble making the tables independent of one another. When adding a new table, it should be "seeded" with the default values per dataframe `data1` and its related `rowNames1`, but thereafter they should be independent as illustrated below. I'm fairly sure the solution has something to do with creating a dynamic equivalent of the reactive `uiTable1` used in the code for holding table values, but I don't know how to do this.

Any ideas for accomplishing this?

Inputs into the base (master) and added tables will be used elsewhere in the full code this is intended for.

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

rowNames1 <- c('A','B','C','Sum') 
data1 <- data.frame(row.names = rowNames1, 'Col 1' = c(1,1,0,2), check.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable1'),    # undeletable base table
  actionButton("addTbl", "Add table"), # adds new table
  tags$div(id = "placeholder")              
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTable1 <- reactiveVal(data1)       # undeletable base table
  rv <- reactiveValues()               # used for dynamic table add/removal
  
  # records changes to base table and will need same for added tables:
  observeEvent(input$hottable1,{uiTable1(hot_to_r(input$hottable1))})
  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTable1(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })
  
  # adds column summation to last row of table, will need for all added tables too:
  observe({
    req(input$hottable1)
    DF <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)
    DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"),]
    DF["Sum",] <- colSums(DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"),, drop = FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)
    uiTable1(DF)
  })
  
  # dynamically add/remove tables:
  observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
    divID <- gsub("\\.", "", format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%OS3")) 
    dtID <- paste0(divID, "DT")
    btnID <- paste0(divID, "rmv")
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      ui = tags$div(id = divID,
                    actionButton(btnID, "Remove table", class = "pull-left btn btn-danger"),
                    rHandsontableOutput(dtID),
                    hr()
      )
    )
    output[[dtID]] <- renderRHandsontable({
      rhandsontable(uiTable1(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
    })
    
    # remove table from the app when remove button clicked
    observeEvent(input[[btnID]], {
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#", divID))
      rv[[divID]] <- NULL
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE, once = TRUE)
  })
  
 }

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Shiny is a reactive framework. You can look at `isolate()`. Read that please https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html

Comment: I see, changing to `output[[dtID]] <- renderRHandsontable({isolate(rhandsontable(uiTable1(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE))})` breaks the dependence to the initial table. Still, added table sums don't work and each added table includes any changes made to the base table. Looks like I need to work on adding ID's to uiTable1 so each added table has its own ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `reactiveValues` to store the information of each new table. These tables will start with the values of the base table available at that time. Afterwards they will stop reacting to changes inside the main table.

First we create the base table `uiTable1 <- reactiveValues(table_base = data1) # undeletable base table`

And finally all the subsequent tables will be created as `uiTable1[[glue("{divID}table")]] <- uiTable$table_base`

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(glue)

rowNames1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "Sum")
data1 <- data.frame(row.names = rowNames1, "Col 1" = c(1, 1, 0, 2), check.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("hottable1"), # undeletable base table
  actionButton("addTbl", "Add table"), # adds new table
  tags$div(id = "placeholder")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTable1 <- reactiveValues(table_base = data1) # undeletable base table
  rv <- reactiveValues() # used for dynamic table add/removal

  # records changes to base table and will need same for added tables:
  observeEvent(input$hottable1, {
    uiTable1$table_base <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)
  })

  output$hottable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTable1$table_base, rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })

  # adds column summation to last row of table, will need for all added tables too:
  observe({
    req(input$hottable1)
    DF <- hot_to_r(input$hottable1)
    DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"), ]
    DF["Sum", ] <- colSums(DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"), , drop = FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)
    uiTable1$table_base <- DF
  })

  # dynamically add/remove tables:
  observeEvent(input$addTbl, {
    divID <- gsub("\\.", "", format(Sys.time(), "%H%M%OS3"))
    dtID <- paste0(divID, "DT")
    btnID <- paste0(divID, "rmv")
    # capture the current state of the main table
    uiTable1[[glue("{divID}table")]] <- uiTable1$table_base

    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      ui = tags$div(
        id = divID,
        actionButton(btnID, "Remove table", class = "pull-left btn btn-danger"),
        rHandsontableOutput(dtID),
        hr()
      )
    )
    output[[dtID]] <- renderRHandsontable({
      req(uiTable1[[glue("{divID}table")]])
      rhandsontable(uiTable1[[glue("{divID}table")]], rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
    })

    # adds column summation to last row of table, will need for all added tables too:
    observeEvent(input[[dtID]], {
      DF <- hot_to_r(input[[dtID]])
      DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"), ]
      DF["Sum", ] <- colSums(DF[setdiff(rowNames1, "Sum"), , drop = FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)
      uiTable1[[glue("{divID}table")]] <- DF # update the table with the sum
    })

    # remove table from the app when remove button clicked
    observeEvent(input[[btnID]],
      {
        removeUI(selector = paste0("#", divID))
        rv[[divID]] <- NULL
        uiTable1[[glue("{divID}table")]] <- NULL
      },
      ignoreInit = TRUE,
      once = TRUE
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I am closely studying this because this will be very useful in other areas of my project. Is `glue(...)` similar to `paste0(...)`? Never used `glue()` before. Btw, I see you are in BA. I am very much looking forward to the Argentina/Croatia match Tuesday night!

Comment: Exactly, `glue("{divID}table")` is like doing `paste0(divID, "table")`.